# counter vector fit transform cosine similarity memory error

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-analysis, cosine-distance

```
count_matrix = count.fit_transform(off_data3['bag_of_words'])
```

I have count_matrix shape with

> count_matrix.shape
>   (476147, 482824)

```
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix, count_matrix)
```

I think the matrix size is too big to cause this memory error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py in
>   cosine_similarity(X, Y, dense_output)    1034     1035     K =
>   safe_sparse_dot(X_normalized, Y_normalized.T,
>   -> 1036                         dense_output=dense_output)    1037     1038     return K
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py in
>   safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
>       135     """
>       136     if sparse.issparse(a) or sparse.issparse(b):
>   --> 137         ret = a * b
>       138         if dense_output and hasattr(ret, "toarray"):
>       139             ret = ret.toarray()
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in
>   **mul**(self, other)
>       479             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
>       480                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
>   --> 481             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
>       482 
>       483         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in
>   _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
>       514                                     maxval=nnz)
>       515         indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
>   --> 516         indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
>       517         data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
>       518
>
> MemoryError:

Any tips to avoid this memory error when You have large matrix?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what is your data and what you are trying to do with it, but from what I gather you are trying to calculate cosine similarity for each pair in a cartesian product, right?

If yes then you might want to use "blocking" to reduce the number of comparisons, see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/54582/64377.